# Retrieving startpoint and endpoint (from/To list) of polyline layer from point layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, fields-attributes, attribute-joins

I am using QGIS 3.8 and I have a polyline layer with the attribute below

[image]

And a point layer with the attribute below

[image]

So I wonder if there is an expression to get the field '**Name**' of the point layer of the nearest points to the startpoint and endpoint into the fields '**from**' & '**To**' of the polyline layer (i.e. the field '**From**' will get the nearest point '**Name**' to the startpoint and the field '**To**' will get the nearest point '**Name**' to the endpoint or vice versa) as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can open the processing toolbox.

Then type in the searcher: `Extract specific vertices`

Choose the `input layer`

In vertex indexes type: `0, -1` (first and last point)

After that you can obtain your lat-lon coordinates creating new fields in the field calculator

Comment: With field calculator, you can also have 
x (start_point($geometry)) and y (start_point($geometry))
x (end_point($geometry)) and y (end_point($geometry))
You can also using geomnearest function if the start and end points of the polylines are not exactly matching with the point layer

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I do not want the the coordinates of the end and start point. I want the fields 'From' and 'To' get the content of the field 'Name'. I used ```geomnearest``` to retrieve the data from the nearest specified layer but I am wondering if I could retrieve the data from the nearest specified layer to the end or start point.